# Why the points List and the agents List are empty in the WaypointsAI script?

Tags: unity, c#

I created a class for the points and agents :

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

```
using System.Linq;
using System;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[Serializable]
public class WaypointsClass
{
    public List<Transform> points = new List<Transform>();
    public List<NavMeshAgent> agents = new List<NavMeshAgent>();
}
```

Then created a script that find waypoints and add them to the points list and agent/s to the agents list:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class RedWaypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] redWaypoints;
    public NavMeshAgent redAgent;

    private void Awake()
    {
        redWaypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Red_Waypoint");

        WaypointsClass wpc = new WaypointsClass();

        foreach (GameObject point in redWaypoints)
        {
            wpc.points.Add(point.transform);
        }

        wpc.agents.Add(redAgent);
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

In the end the WaypointsAI script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointsAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WaypointsClass waypoints;
    public float distanceToContinue;

    private float currentDistanceToPoint;
    private int lastPointIndex;
    private int goalPointIndex;

    void Start()
    {
        //Firstly check if the waypoints are set up correctly
        if (waypoints.points.Count < 1)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Set up the waypoints for this gameObject!");
        }
        else
        {
            //Now set up the path
            lastPointIndex = 0; //Start from the index 0
            waypoints.agents[0].transform.position = waypoints.points[0].position;
            if (waypoints.points.Count > 1)
            {
                goalPointIndex = 1; //Go to the [1] waypoint
            }
            else
            {
                goalPointIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.agents.Count; i++)
        {
            //Calculate the distance and check if it should move to the next waypoint.
            currentDistanceToPoint = Vector3.Distance(waypoints.agents[i].transform.position, waypoints.points[goalPointIndex].position);
            if (currentDistanceToPoint <= distanceToContinue)
            {
                //Save the old index, totally useless in this implementation though
                lastPointIndex = goalPointIndex;
                //Increase goal index to change the goal waypoint to the next, (Or maybe random one?)
                goalPointIndex++;
                if (goalPointIndex >= waypoints.points.Count)
                    goalPointIndex = 0;
            }

            //Now move towards the current waypoint, Change this to fit your code with navMesh anyway I think I did a lot for you anyway
            waypoints.agents[i].transform.LookAt(waypoints.points[goalPointIndex].position);
            waypoints.agents[i].transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the first line in the WaypointsAI script the points List is empty :

```
if (waypoints.points.Count < 1)
```

points is empty. How can I resolve it ?

Comment: In future, please use the *edit* link to add more information to your existing question, instead of posting a duplicate. Posting duplicates looks like spam to our automated systems, and can lead to restrictions on your account.

Comment: You create a temporary instance of the WaypointsClass in your RedWaypoints's Awake() method, then allow it to go out of scope and be devoured by the garbage collector at the end of that method. Your WaypointsAI has its own, unrelated instance of the WaypointsClass that doesn't know anything about what transpired in RedWaypoints.Awake. It looks like you may want to work through some more introductory C# tutorials to understand how the language works.